# Javascript using same variable in calculation

Tags: javascript, node-red

I'm trying to get a calculation to work in javascript, but have failed miserably!
The calculation is technically known as a 'August-Roche-Magnus approximation' and is used to calculate relative humidity from the 2 variables - dewpoint and temp.

```
var humidity = (100*(((17.625 * dewpoint)/(243.04 + dewpoint))/((17.625 * temp)/(243.04 + temp))));
```

The 2 variables, `dewpoint` & `temp` are derived from a xml feed, and the result from the calculation is `NaN`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Paul

Comment: Most likely your values received from the XML are still string values – you’ll have to convert them to integer or float first, using `parseInt`/`parseFloat`.

Comment: Standard debugging technique on something like this is to investigate the values you have in the variables. You can use the console for that.

Answer (score 0):

Alert the values that are from the xml and test the most common issue could be of the data value format. For calculation you should have float values and float conversion could be gotten by `parseFloat(value)`

Answer (score 0):

The javascript expression evaluates to `NaN` if either `temp` or `dewpoint` are `NaN`, or if both `temp` and `dewpoint` are `0`. I suspect this may be the problem. I'm also a bit unsure about your formula. If `temp = 0` and `dewpoint = -1`, it returns `-Infinity`. I'm assuming the formula uses Celsius degrees: a quick look on Wikipedia appears to confirm this.